# Can Someone Explain How the ball went forward from the camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```c#
private void Update()
{
    Ball.transform.position = PlayerCamera.transform.position + 
                              PlayerCamera.transform.forward * DistanceBall;
}
```

Comment: it is clearly stated in the fragment you pasted (without correct formatting) how the ball went forward. I have a feeling your question might not be suited for SO

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty unclear question, but....

I will assume that you are trying to understandd better how the ball moves from the code you have given.

It looks like you are setting the ball's position to be the player's camera position plus the amount they have moved forward multiplied by the constant ball distance.

So whenever you move forward the PlayerCamera.transform.forward changes and so that adds or subtracts from the Ball.transform.position.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56331499/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at some basic API pages like [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html), [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), [`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) and [`Transform.forawrd`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html).

For the calculation itself a look at [Vector3 * operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_multiply.html) would also be helpful.

```c#
// This method is automatically called by Unity every frame
private void Update()
{
    Ball.transform.position = 
        // This is the PlayerCamera's position
        PlayerCamera.transform.position 
        // This is the PlayerCamera's forward vector with magnitude 1
        // so this would move the ball 1 Unity Unit in front of the camera
        + PlayerCamera.transform.forward 
        // This finally moves the desired distance in front of the camera instead of 1 Unit
        * DistanceBall;
}
```

The `transform.forward` is a `Vector3` that always points in the positive local `Z` axis. It is the local forward vector but returned in World space coordinates.

---

I general I would actually always recommend to use [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) isntead if the camera is moved by any user input. This way you can handle all user input in `Update` and make the moving of the ball rather the latest step before rendering.

---

In general I would recommend to go through some basic Unity Tutorials like e.g. [Update and FixedUpdate](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate?playlist=17117) and [Vector Maths](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/vector-maths?playlist=17117) before touching code ;)